# Is it possible to use Phonegap to bring a PlayN game to iOS?

Tags: ios, html, cordova, playn

[PlayN](http://code.google.com/p/playn/) looks like a pretty impressive way to develop Html5 games. I'm wondering if if there are any efforts to make the html/javascript output compatible with [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) with the end result being an iOS executable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PlayN works just fine with PhoneGap, and in Mobile Safari. Performance is not awesome because in PhoneGap, you cannot use JIT compiled JavaScript. Also, prior to iOS5, Canvas was not hardware accelerated. PlayN has a DOM+CSS backend for HTML5 that achieves decent performance on iOS4 and earlier, but it is being phased out in favor of a Canvas-only HTML5 backend. So that's added complexity if you want to target iOS via HTML5 + PhoneGap.

PlayN will eventually support iOS natively, and that will be a vastly preferable way to deploy to iOS because it will be more correct, higher performance, and integrate more easily with existing iOS services.